# Using py-postgresql with SQLAlchemy raises No module named postgresql.driver

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to use the py-postgresql driver with SQLAlchemy.  However, I get the following `ImportError`.  I am using Python 2.7.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ed/projects/wiki/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from database import db_session as db
  File "/home/ed/projects/wiki/database.py", line 5, in <module>
    engine = create_engine('postgresql+pypostgresql://ed:noles98@127.0.0.1:5432/wiki', convert_unicode=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 386, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 75, in create
    dbapi = dialect_cls.dbapi(**dbapi_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/pypostgresql.py", line 65, in dbapi
    from postgresql.driver import dbapi20
ImportError: No module named postgresql.driver
```

Comment: Please add background information. What have you already tried for instance. Are there any other technologies involved?

Comment: `pip install py-postgresql`

Comment: I installed psycpog2 per a comment on IRC and py-postgresql per a comment on the web.

Comment: py-postgresql is python3 only

Comment: sqlalchemy and postgresql are involved.